# OpenVPN routing and cascading

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn

Take a look at my current VPN setup. I'm going to call the servers 'prince', 'castle', 'dragon' accordingly'

```
 ________   prince is a         ________    dragon is a client     ________
|        |  client of castle   |        |       of prince         |        |
| castle |<--------------------| prince |<------------------------| dragon |
|________|    vpn subnet is    |________|   ifconfig 172.16.0.61  |________|
    |         10.10.160.0/24                is a vpn gateway           |
    |                                          on dragon               | 
 some lan X                                                        some lan Y
10.10.150.0/24                                                    10.0.6.0/24
```

What I want to achieve is being able to access castle's subnet (X) 10.10.150.0 from dragon.

So, for example if there's a machine in the castle lan (X) with an address of 10.10.150.65 I should be able to access it from dragon (and machines in lan Y).

**Castle (server) configuration:**

```
port 5010
proto udp
dev tap10

#(ca,cert,key,dh here)#
cipher AES-256-CBC

server 10.10.160.0 255.255.255.0
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"

route 10.10.150.0 255.255.255.0
route 10.10.160.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 10.10.150.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 10.10.160.0 255.255.255.0"

keepalive 10 120

comp-lzo
duplicate-cn

user nobody
group nogroup

persist-key
persist-tun

log-append /var/log/openvpn/tap10_server.log
verb 3
```

**Prince (client) configuration:**

```
client
port 5010
remote 88.99.x.x #(public ip of castle)

#(ca,cert,key,dh here)#

cipher AES-256-CBC
dev tap10
proto udp
nobind
auth-nocache
persist-key
persist-tun
key-direction 1
comp-lzo
verb 3
log-append /var/log/openvpn/tap10_client.log
```

**Prince (server) configuration:**

```
port 5002
dev tap2

ifconfig 172.16.0.61 255.255.255.252

tls-server
#(pkcs12 and dh here)#

cipher AES-256-CBC

max-clients 3

user nobody
group nogroup

comp-lzo

ping 5
ping-restart 15
ping-timer-rem
persist-tun
persist-key

push "route-gateway 172.16.0.61"

push "route 10.10.150.0 255.255.255.0 vpn_gateway"

verb 3
log-append /var/log/openvpn/tap2.log
```

**Dragon (client) configuration:**

```
client
port 5002
remote 66.77.x.x #(public address of prince)
dev tap0

ifconfig 172.16.0.62 255.255.255.252

#(pkcs12 here)
cipher AES-256-CBC

user nobody
group nogroup

comp-lzo

ping 15
ping-restart 45
ping-timer-rem
persist-tun
persist-key


verb 3
log-append /var/log/openvpn/tap0_client.log
```

So at the moment I can access castle's lan (X) from prince, but not from dragon. How should I setup the routes to make it work?

I hope my explanation is not too messy.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenVPN won't modify the server routes for subnets outside the client networks unless you explicitly tell it to.

In your diagram, it's not clear if the machine *castle* has a route to *dragon* through *prince*.

You need to inform castle that the way to reach network 10.0.6.0/24 (*dragon* LAN) is through the *prince* client connection.

If you have only one OpenVPN client you can just add a route in the *castle* conf (that *prince* is a client of):

`route 10.0.6.0 255.255.255.0`

This isn't enough if you have multiple clients connecting to that server, the server won't know which client to assign the route to.  In that case you need to do client-specific configuration.

`client-config-dir client-configs`

This would instruct the OpenVPN server to look for client-specific config files in subdirectory `client-configs` (of the conf directory on the server) for files that match the client CN name name on the certificate the client uses to connect.  So *castle* would look for a file `client-configs/prince` and use those config directives when a client connects with a certificate matching `prince` (you need to be sure the CN on the certificate matches the filename, OpenVPN doesn't care what *you* call the machines).

In that client config file `client-configs\prince`, the *prince* specific parts:

`iroute 10.0.6.0 255.255.255.0
[...]`

The `iroute` statement tells the OpenVPN server to route traffic for that subnet through the client, the earlier `route 10.0.6.0 255.255.255.0` statement tells the kernel on `castle` to let OpenVPN manage the route for that network.

More details at [The OpenVPN HOWTO](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html) under "**Including multiple machines on the client side when using a routed VPN (dev tun)**".

The machine *prince* will also need to forward IP traffic if it isn't already, since you're using it as a router in this configuration.

Comment: Your answer pointed me into right direction. Thank you!